# Cannot add my domain to 'App Domains' in Facebook App

Tags: facebook, wordpress, facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps

I was creating a app in Facebook. Its for facebook comment box in my website. But when trying to add my domain, its showing an error like in the screenshot. I tried removing 'www.', adding 'http://' etc. But not use. I also tried some other domains. Still same error. Can any one tell me the reason.? pls
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error message is already saying, the App Domain has to be derived from on of the listed URLs. To "fix" the issue, add "Website" as a platform, and set the URL to http://www.exklusiveconnextions.com, save it and you're done. You can now set the App Domain to exklusiveconnextions.com.

Comment: Just for the record, I got caught up on this because I was trying to use an IP and not a domain name. For some stupid reason it has to be a registered domain name, even if its a test app.